# Flutter Firebase Push Notification on IOS, message received but never pushed to system tray

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter application sample, I used firebase_messaging to connect to Firebase and get push notification, I followed the instruction in their documentation https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging in details and did configuration from Android and IOS, its woking fine for Android but Not in IOS, I have created all certificates and keys necessary from Apple developer console and connected my app to Firebase Console by uploading signing key. And added the permission request to send push notification for IOS, but never seen a notification shown on phone tray like Android. here is my full code:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'widget/messaging_widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String appTitle = 'Firebase messaging';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    title: appTitle,
    home: MainPage(appTitle: appTitle),
  );
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String appTitle;

  const MainPage({this.appTitle});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(appTitle),
    ),
    body: MessagingWidget(),
  );
}
```

message.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class Message {
  final String title;
  final String body;

  const Message({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.body,
  });
}
```

message_widget.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../model/message.dart';

class MessagingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessagingWidgetState createState() => _MessagingWidgetState();
}

class _MessagingWidgetState extends State<MessagingWidget> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final List<Message> messages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
        setState(() {
          messages.add(Message(
              title: notification['title'], body: notification['body']));
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");

        final notification = message['data'];
        setState(() {
          messages.add(Message(
            title: '${notification['title']}',
            body: '${notification['body']}',
          ));
        });
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView(
    children: messages.map(buildMessage).toList(),
  );

  Widget buildMessage(Message message) => ListTile(
    title: Text(message.title),
    subtitle: Text(message.body),
  );
}
```

When I send test message from Firebase console while the app is on and active, onMessage get called and the message shows on gthe app successfully like the images below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But when the app is not On or in background, nothing happens although I have added the Background Modes (background fetch, remote notification, background processing) and Push Notification Capabilities to the certificate.

Comment: hey, did find a solution? I have the same problem now.

Comment: The Push notification is not working on a simulator. Please use real device to test it.